How to retrieve entries when selecting dates when clicking on different dates through CalendarView
I'm trying to query entries (1 or more) from clicking my CalendarView on the screen, but I got stuck in trying to figure out how to continue on in order to display these entries as I'm new. I didn't understand the view model so it's quite difficult to figure out that part out for me as there is also an error for asking me to pass in parameters.
Screen (I'm trying to convert dates into Long without the time to query the database and load the entries with the specific dates but I couldn't really find what I need to load the entries into a variable to pass into the entry card function):
fun CalendarScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: EntryViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    var queryDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        AndroidView(factory = { CalendarView(it) }, update = {
            it.setOnDateChangeListener { calendarView, year, month, day ->
                //query only the date
                queryDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                    set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
                    set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                    set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
                    set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                    set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                    set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day)
                }
                val queryDateInLong = queryDate.timeInMillis //Convert date to long
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.loadEntryList(queryDateInLong)
                }
            }
        }
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        LazyColumn(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)) {
            stickyHeader {
                Text("Entries", fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif, fontSize = 22.sp)
                }
            entries.forEach { entry ->
                EntryCard(entry)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun EntryCard(entry: Entry) {
    var cardColor = ""
    //Compare emotion input from entry to map to retrieve # color string
    if (emotionToColor.containsKey(entry.emotionEntry)) {
        cardColor = emotionToColor[entry.emotionEntry].toString()
    }
    val cardColorBackground = cardColor.toColor() //Convert to color for card
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val dateConvert = Calendar.getInstance().apply { timeInMillis = entry.dateEntryInMillis }
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(cardColorBackground)
            .height(35.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { expanded = !expanded }
    ) {
        AnimatedContent(
            targetState = expanded,
            transitionSpec = {
                fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(150,150)) togetherWith
                        fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(150)) using
                        SizeTransform { initialSize, targetSize ->
                            if (targetState) {
                                keyframes {
                                    IntSize(targetSize.width, initialSize.height) at 150
                                    durationMillis = 300
                                }
                            } else {
                                keyframes { IntSize(initialSize.width, targetSize.height) at 150
                                    durationMillis = 300
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }, label = ""
        ) { targetExpanded ->
            if (targetExpanded) {
                Text(text = entry.journalEntry,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Justify)
            } else {
                Text(text = "${entry.emotionEntry}: $dateConvert ${entry.timeEntry}", fontSize = 24.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
            }

        }

    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
}

Data Repo:
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(private val entryDAO: EntryDAO, private val date: Long) {
    suspend fun saveEntry(entry: Entry) {
        return entryDAO.saveEntry(entry)
    }
    suspend fun deleteEntry(entry: Entry) {
        return entryDAO.deleteEntry(entry)
    }
    suspend fun getEntryFromDate(date: Long): List<Entry> {
        return entryDAO.getEntryFromDate(this.date)
    }
}

Entry class
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table")
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Emotion") val emotionEntry: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Journal") val journalEntry: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Date") val dateEntryInMillis: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Time") val timeEntry: String
    ) {

}

DAO Class
@Dao
interface EntryDAO {

    @Upsert
    suspend fun saveEntry(entry: Entry)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteEntry(entry: Entry)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM entry_table WHERE Date = :dateInLong") //retrieve emotion, journal, time and date from a date
    suspend fun getEntryFromDate(dateInLong: Long): List<Entry>

}

ViewModel (I was following a github of a guide for making the hilt room database to work but I don't really understand much of making a view model):
There is also an error to the init { loadEntryList() } for not having a parameter for the date but I'm not sure what to put in it.
Error:
"No value passed for parameter 'date'"
@HiltViewModel
class EntryViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: DataRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _entries = mutableStateOf<List<Entry>>(emptyList())
    val entries: State<List<Entry>> = _entries

    fun loadEntryList(date: Long) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _entries.value = repository.getEntryFromDate(date)
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveEntry(entry: Entry) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.saveEntry(entry)
        }
    }
}

I'm hoping that when I click on any dates on the CalendarView, the app would convert the date into Long and query the 'DateInMillis' from the entry class and then load all the entries so that it can be used with the Entry Card function to display the entries.
Thanks!

I managed to retrieve the query and load it into the screen by adding
val dateEntries = viewModel.entries.value

To the top of the CalendarScreen, in addition to Dj aman motihari's answer.
